# Message lost in paho-mqtt

Tags: python, paho, emq

I am using paho-mqtt to receive data from emqx broker but I am losing data because sometimes my paho-mqtt subscriber goes down. Any method to get data when I will run subscriber again it will give all published data.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no subscriber, EMQ x will discard the message, which is a normal design.

You can try EMQ x enterprise and use backend for offline data storage.

https://docs.emqx.io/tutorial/latest/en/backend/whats_backend.html

Comment: Thanks @wivwiv I will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I hope you get a solution.
I don't know your client , but paho-mqtt java client can reconnect automatically. This reconnect can be check in  "connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String s)" boolean parameter

```
public class MqttautoClient implements MqttCallbackExtended {

.
.
.
    @Override
    public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection connectComplete");
    }
    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection lost");
    }
    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "messageArrived");
    }
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        Log.d(TAG, "deliveryComplete ");
    }


}
```